# Resize canvas by half imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

How to resize a image of variable sizes to half of its current size?

That is :
30x30 to 15x15
40x40 to 20x20
60x60 to 30x30

Gravity:Top-Left

Comment: This question is not clear. Do you want the image to be resized? Or do you want the same size, but cropped at half the size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated Yet Again**

```
convert input.png -extent 50% -background none output.png
```

**Updated Again**

Maybe you mean this:

```
convert input.jpg -extent 50% output.jpg
```

**Updated Answer**

Maybe you mean cropping out the centre of the image like this:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity center -crop 50% output.jpg
```

**Original Answer**

Like this:

```
identify input.jpg    # Check dimensions of input image
input.jpg JPEG 304x304 304x304+0+0 8-bit sRGB 37KB 0.000u 0:00.000

# Convert the image to half its size
convert input.jpg -resize 50% output.jpg

identify output.jpg   # Check dimensions of output image
output.jpg JPEG 152x152 152x152+0+0 8-bit sRGB 20.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: -resize resizes the image, what i want to do is resize the canvas of the image

Comment: I don't understand. How will a red rectangle 100px wide and 50px high look after you reduce its size by 50%?

Comment: I had another try - please look again.

Comment: I had another try - please look again.

Comment: convert input.jpg -extent 50% output.jpg
It worked but background becomes non-transparent.

Comment: If you are using transparency, you need to use `PNG` or `GIF` rather than `JPEG`.

Comment: I know that,I did change the code from jpg to png and the image formats were also in png format but when i see the output.png a while background appears behind it.

Comment: Can you post a link to an image?

Comment: I had another try - please look again.

Comment: Upon checking it was my mistake :p

Comment: What's the difference between `-resize 50%` and `-extent 50%` ?

Comment: @Flimm If you use `-resize 50%` the output image will be half the size of the input image but still contain all the original content, just smaller. If you use `-extent 50%` the output image will be half the size of the original but parts of the original image will not be present - they'll be cropped out.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with the GUI, clicking View > Half Size (or resize for other proportions) and View > Apply. After that, you save your image. Through the console, adding the following arguments:

```
$ display -write ./output.png -resize 50% original.png
```

Comment: `-resize 50%` is what I was looking for. Didn't realize that was a thing.